# Access upstream job parameters in downstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized upstream build A that should remain untouched as far as possible. Now I want to configure my downstream build B with a declarative pipeline.

So I defined in the Jekinsfile of project B in the `triggers` section a upstream relation to A. But now I'm stuck with getting the build parameters of build A.

So far I came across the following Ideas:

- Using the [Jenkins job API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) (I would only do this if there is no way to specify this directly in a Jenkinsfile)
- From my current view using the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) is not a an option since I do not want to reconfigure the upstream job when another downstream job is added.

In my Jenkinsfile of job B I would like to do something like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent docker
    environment {
        FOO = ""
    }
    triggers {
        upstream(upstreamProjects: 'A', threshold: hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Print params') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // I would expect something like this to access the FOO variable of job A
                    // ${env.FOO} = job('A').params.FOO
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to directly access parameters of the build from job A that triggered the current build of job B.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just parametrize the downstream job and pass the parameters on the call.

```
build job: 'your-downstream-job', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'YOUR_STRING_PARAM', value: "${yourRandomGeneratedStringVariable}" ]]
```

Comment: How can I pass the parameters to the downstream job?

Comment: Edited my post with an example

Comment: Thank you for the example. But I would need to add this to job A? However, I do not want to create a dependency from job A to job B but vice versa.

Comment: I would rather say that's bad design.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? My thought was that project A from a source code perspective has no dependency on project B. Therefore I also do not want to introduce a dependency in my build system that suddenly introduces one. But since I have not found a suitable solution for our Jenkins setup here at the company I will take your suggested solution and change the Jenkinsfile of job A.

Comment: If B is parametrized (takes in arguments so to say) it could be reused not only by A, but C, D etc. If B has to have knowledge of A, well that's tight coupling.